# How to get matching all matching occurences in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file of the following:

```
Question:What color is the sky?
Explanation:The sky reflects the ocean.

Question:Why did the chicken cross the road?
Explanation:He was hungry.
```

What I'm trying to obtain is a list of `("What color is the sky?", "Why did the chicken cross the road")`

I'm trying to use perl regex to parse this file, but with no luck.

I have the entire contents of my file in a string called `$file`, and this is what I'm trying

```
my @questions = ($file =~ /Question:(.*)\n/g);
```

But this always just returns the entire `$file` string to me.

Comment: Works for me, how are you getting the string? Was able to reproduce your issue by putting it all on the same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `(.*)` is greedily matching the whole line until it gets to the `\n`, which is probably a result of how you are getting the string.

You can add a `?` to make the match not greedy.

So try

```
    my @questions = ($file =~ /Question:(.*?\?)/g);
```

Notice I escaped `\?`, so the regex will match up to the questionmark

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole file in a value will occupy too many memory if the is large, a better way is to process the file line by line.

For example you could do something like

```
my @questions;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (m/Question:(.*)/) {
        push @questions, $1;
    }
}
```

---

Some explanations:

1. [I/O Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) of `perlop`:

> Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line.

Comment: @Nosrettap `<>` means reading from all command line files one by one, and if no such files, reading from `STDIN`.